# Is it possible to run multiple commands through one process?

Tags: c#, cmd, process

I have a function that sends commands to cmd.exe using System.Diagnostics.Process, however I need to loop through a set of arguments for this command and each loop opens a new cmd.exe which used a lot of unnecessary cpu power.

Currently I'm using a for loop that increment to the next item in a list to pass to ProcessStartInfo. I need to have each argument called on it's own line.
ie. 
/C myFunction.exe MyList[0]
/C myFunction.exe MyList[1]
...etc

The code I currently have sets the values in MyList to 0-24, given the outer for loop, through myFunction.exe which is called in cmd.exe.

```cs
            Process process = new Process();
            ProcessStartInfo StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            for (int j = 0; j < 25; j++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Device_Numbers.Count; i++)
                {
                    StartInfo.Arguments = "/C myFunction.exe " + i + " = " + j;
                    process.StartInfo = StartInfo;
                    process.Start();
                }
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
            }
```

The call to cmd.exe works however it opens up a new cmd.exe window for every iteration through i, and it would be better if I could open one window and iterate through i all in that one window.

Comment: Why do you need a command window at all? Can you not start `myFunction.exe` directly?

Comment: Create a batch file containing all the `myFunction.exe` that you want to execute, and run the batch file with `Process`.

Comment: Because it has arguments it opens a cmd window no matter what.. The problem is I need it to run the function with argumens 1-52 potentially and I don't want 52 cmd windows opening when it does this.

Answer (score 0):

The first `using` block creates a batch file with all the commands to be executed. The second `using` block executes the batch file.

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("myFunctions.cmd"))
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 25; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Device_Numbers.Count; i++)
        {
            sw.WriteLine("myFunction.exe " + i + " = " + j);
        }
    }
}

using (Process process = new Process())
{
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C myFunctions.cmd";
    process.Start();
    process.WaitForExit();
}
```

Comment: @Aaron Lind - Did this answer your question?